# Updating the background colour in Toplevel widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I am trying to update the background color of a TopLevel widget via a radio button. 
What I want is to have the background color change when the user changes the radio button.
Currently, the program opens a new window, with a radio button. The back ground color does not change at all.

```
from tkinter import *

class Example:

    def newWindow(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        v = IntVar()
        v.set(-1)
        self.aRadioButton = Radiobutton(top, text="Blue",variable = v, value = 0)
        self.aRadioButton.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.aRadioButton = Radiobutton(top, text="Red",variable = v, value = 1)
        self.aRadioButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

        if v == 0:
            top.configure(bg="Blue")
        elif v == 1:
            top.configure(bg="Red")


    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master, width = 50, height = 50)
        frame.grid()

        self.aLabel = Label(frame, text = "New window bg colour").grid(row=0)

        self.aButton = Button(frame, text="To new window", command=self.newWindow)
        self.aButton.grid(row=1)

root = Tk()
app = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There has to be some kind of event, when you change the radio button... there should go your color change. `newWindow` is called only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an event, when you change the radio button.
Attach command method to the radiobuttons like this:

```
self.aRadioButton = Radiobutton(top, text="Blue",variable = v, value = 0, command=lambda: top.configure(bg="Blue"))
self.aRadioButton = Radiobutton(top, text="Red",variable = v, value = 1, command=lambda: top.configure(bg="Red"))
```

Also when you do this, you don't need the variable `v` if you used it only for this purpouse.